# Entity Framework, Enum Support: Modify Expression in Linq Extension Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm attempting to implement Entity Framework and I need enum support, so I'm trying to piggy-back off of what is outlined in this blog: http://rogeralsing.com/2010/11/10/entity-framework-4-enum-support-in-linq/. I need to take this a step further because my enum value is stored as a string (changing the database is not an option, unfortunately). In referenced link, what the author is basically doing is replacing the unmapped enum property with a mapped integer property within the linq expression. What I'm attempting to do is also replace the value thats being referenced with an equivalent 'enum-based' string value. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability, you may just try using the June CTP of Entity Framework, which allows enum support built-in.  It's been working great for me, and no work-arounds.

Info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

Download: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221760